# How to search for multiple patterns in a single regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to write python script where I open/read a log file and pull out specific information such as the below:

Mac address, IP address, Total number of acks

To pull out the information I know I will need a regex and my current regex is below

```
"(([0-9a-f]{2}:){5}[0-9a-f]{2}) via (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})"
```

I'm still working on pulling the ACK aka DHCPACK requests only. But what I'm having a hard time with is pulling the IP address. A snippet of the log I have to read/extract is below:

```
Mar 15 09:17:29 linux1 dhcpd: uid lease 10.119.127.14 for client 2c:44:fd:02:02:3b is duplicate on 10.119.0/17
Mar 15 09:17:29 linux1 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.119.79.13 (10.1.2.27) from 2c:44:fd:02:02:3b via 10.119.0.1
**Mar 15 09:17:29 linux1 dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.119.79.13 to 2c:44:fd:02:02:3b via 10.119.0.1**
Mar 15 09:17:29 linux1 dhcpd: DHCPDECLINE of 10.119.79.13 from 2c:44:fd:02:02:3b via 10.119.0.1: not found
Mar 15 09:17:30 linux1 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.172.219.117 from 84:8e:0c:1d:58:60 (iPhone) via 10.172.192.1
**Mar 15 09:17:30 linux1 dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.172.219.117 to 84:8e:0c:1d:58:60 (iPhone) via 10.172.192.1**
Mar 15 09:17:30 linux1 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 9c:b7:0d:8a:29:65 via 10.145.192.1: network 10.145.192/19: no free leases
Mar 15 09:17:31 linux1 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.119.222.25 from c8:f6:50:d6:ce:be (63074) via 10.119.192.1
Mar 15 09:17:31 linux1 dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.119.222.25 to c8:f6:50:d6:ce:be (63074) via 10.119.192.1
```

I can pull the first ACK just fine but they don't all have the same format/pattern. For example, the first bolded line is 'MAC via IP' and the second bolded is 'MAC (iphone) via IP'.

I'm new to regex's so not sure if there is a way to search for both patterns or if I simply need to make two separate regexs for each pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex pattern :

```
(([0-9a-f]{2}:){5}[0-9a-f]{2})( \(\w+\))? via (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
```

It matches with all cases where it might have some extra words in brackets in between the mac address and the `via` word and that part is made optional.

For the input text provided, the regex matches are :

```
2c:44:fd:02:02:3b via 10.119.0.1
2c:44:fd:02:02:3b via 10.119.0.1
2c:44:fd:02:02:3b via 10.119.0.1
84:8e:0c:1d:58:60 (iPhone) via 10.172.192.1
84:8e:0c:1d:58:60 (iPhone) via 10.172.192.1
9c:b7:0d:8a:29:65 via 10.145.192.1
c8:f6:50:d6:ce:be (63074) via 10.119.192.1
c8:f6:50:d6:ce:be (63074) via 10.119.192.1
```

For better visualization, check the matches [here](https://regex101.com/r/eWVMdb/1).

Comment: Thank you! I was able to build off your regex and get the data I needed

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can give you a start.

```
txt = """\
Mar 15 09:17:29 linux1 dhcpd: uid lease 10.119.127.14 for client 2c:44:fd:02:02:3b is duplicate on 10.119.0/17
Mar 15 09:17:29 linux1 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.119.79.13 (10.1.2.27) from 2c:44:fd:02:02:3b via 10.119.0.1
Mar 15 09:17:29 linux1 dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.119.79.13 to 2c:44:fd:02:02:3b via 10.119.0.1
Mar 15 09:17:29 linux1 dhcpd: DHCPDECLINE of 10.119.79.13 from 2c:44:fd:02:02:3b via 10.119.0.1: not found
Mar 15 09:17:30 linux1 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.172.219.117 from 84:8e:0c:1d:58:60 (iPhone) via 10.172.192.1
Mar 15 09:17:30 linux1 dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.172.219.117 to 84:8e:0c:1d:58:60 (iPhone) via 10.172.192.1
Mar 15 09:17:30 linux1 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 9c:b7:0d:8a:29:65 via 10.145.192.1: network 10.145.192/19: no free leases
Mar 15 09:17:31 linux1 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.119.222.25 from c8:f6:50:d6:ce:be (63074) via 10.119.192.1
Mar 15 09:17:31 linux1 dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.119.222.25 to c8:f6:50:d6:ce:be (63074) via 10.119.192.1"""

import re

for ln in txt.splitlines():
    if not 'DHCPACK' in ln:
        continue
    parts = re.findall( r"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)|(([\da-f]+:){5}[\da-f]+)", ln )
    print(parts[0][0], "---", parts[1][1])
```

Output:

```
10.119.79.13 --- 2c:44:fd:02:02:3b
10.172.219.117 --- 84:8e:0c:1d:58:60
10.119.222.25 --- c8:f6:50:d6:ce:be
```